# How to remove weights on vertices (2.8)

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, vertex-weights

So for some context: I uploaded a model to Mixamo to get a rig for it, and this rig works fairly well, with the only problem being that the character's tail is distorted. I would like to remove the influence of the bones on the tail, but I can't seem to do this.

I've tried two different ways, both with similar outcomes:
 - Weight painting: tried painting with weight 0 on the tail region, ended up still having the tail weight be present with weird spikes in the tail
 - Changing vertex weights in edit mode: highlighted the tail region with circle highlighting, set weights to 0, also got weird spikes in the tail and a bunch of tail vertices still had weights on them

What's the proper way to do this?